# Combine count rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've got a table in MySQL that looks roughly like:

```
value | count
-------------
Fred  | 7
FRED  | 1
Roger | 3
roger | 1
```

That is, it was created with string ops outside of MySQL, so the values are case- and trailing-whitespace-sensitive.

I want it to look like:

```
value | count
-------------
Fred  | 8
Roger | 4
```

That is, managed by MySQL, with `value` a primary key.  It's not important which one (of "Fred" or "FRED") is kept.

I know how to do this in code.  I also know how to generate a list of problem values (with a self-join).  But I'd like to come up with a SQL update/delete to migrate my table, and I can't think of anything.

If I knew that no pair of records had variants of one value, with the same count (like ("Fred",4) and ("FRED",4)), then I think I can do it with a self-join to copy the counts, and then an update to remove the zeros.  But I have no such guarantee.

Is there something simple I'm missing, or is this one of those cases where you just write a short function outside of the database?

Thanks!

Comment: you should normalize your strings before insertion, you'll be saving yourself a lot of trouble

Comment: mcabral: In general I agree, though in the context of my actual data it's not clear what 'normalized' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, MySQL seems to do this for you.  I just tested this in MySQL 5.1.47:

```
create table c (value varchar(10), count int);
insert into c values ('Fred',7), ('FRED',1), ('Roger',3), ('roger',1);

select * from c;

+-------+-------+
| value | count |
+-------+-------+
| Fred  |     7 |
| FRED  |     1 |
| Roger |     3 |
| roger |     1 |
+-------+-------+

select value, sum(count) from c group by value;

+-------+------------+
| value | sum(count) |
+-------+------------+
| Fred  |          8 |
| Roger |          4 |
+-------+------------+
```

I was surprised to see MySQL transform the strings like that, and I'm not sure I can explain why it did that.  I was expecting to have to get four distinct rows, and to have to use some string functions to map the values to a canonical form.

Comment: It's not changing the names, your GROUP BY clause is simply using the first occurrence as the value in the resultset; both of which are name case.

Comment: have you tried with different amounts of trailing whitespaces?

Comment: @mcabral: That should only matter if the data type is CHAR

Comment: You're right, I was thinking it was far more complex than it turned out to be.  Great!

Comment: mcabral: Seems to work (i.e., do what I want) in that respect, too.

Comment: The behavior may be due to the collation

Answer (score 2):

As an example of how to obtain the results you are looking for with a SQL query alone:

```
SELECT UPPER(value) AS name, SUM(count) AS qty FROM table GROUP BY name;
```

If you make a new table to hold the correct values, you INSERT the above query to populate the new table as so:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (SELECT UPPER(value) AS name, SUM(count) AS qty FROM table GROUP BY name);
```